# A trivial inequality in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

> Let, $C(T)$ be the semi-circle centered at $c(>0)\in \Bbb R$ and radius $T$ lying to the left of the vertical segment. If $z=x+iy\in C(T)$ then for all large $T$ we have, $\displaystyle |z(z+1)|\ge \frac{T^2}{2}$.

My book says this. I think it is trivial one, but I'm unable to prove this. I've tried by putting $z=x+iy$ and also $z=c+Te^{i\theta}$. But I'm not getting the result. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|z| \geq T-c$ so $|z(z+1)| \geq (T-c)(T-c-1) >(T-c-1)^{2}>\frac {T^{2}} 2$ for $T$ sufficiently large. In fact this is true for $T > \frac {1+c} {1-\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}}$

Comment: How you get the last inequality ?

Comment: Upto $|z| \geq T-c$ so $|z(z+1)| \geq (T-c)(T-c-1)$ I've already got in my work..But I'm not getting the last one.

Comment: @Topo What you need is $T-c-1> \frac T {\sqrt 2}$. Just transfer the right side to the left side and $c+1$ to the right side.